# How to delete multi level referenced schemas in Mongo-DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, mongoose

I am creating a ERP system in which School have courses and Courses contain Students.I want to impelement API to delete a school which also deletes courses and all the students enrolled in courses .

This is what i am doing in API logic:-

```
app.delete("/fetchSchool/:schoolId", async (req, res) => {
try {
    const deletedSchool = await schools.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.schoolId);
    (!deletedSchool) ? res.send('Invalid Request'):
    courses.remove({_id: {$in: deletedSchool.course}}, (error, deletedCourse) => {
        error ? res.send('Subsequent Deletion Of Course Failed'):
        students.remove({_id: {$in: deletedCourse.students}}, (error, response) => {
            error ? res.send(error): res.send('Deletion Successfull');
        })
    })

 } catch (error) {
     res.status(500).send('some error occured,' + error.message);
 }
})
```

But this only deletes school and courses in school but students data still present.

This is my schema:-

School Schema

```
 const SchoolSchema = mongoose.Schema({
 course: [{
     type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     ref: 'course'
  }] 
 })
```

Course Schema

```
const CourseSchema = mongoose.Schema({
students: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'student'
 }]
})
```

Student Schema

```
const StudentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
}})
```

Please let me know the corect way to delete students also along with school and courses.

Comment: Have you considered using a relational database management system?

Comment: I am building this as a project in my ongoing intership and they have asked me to use Mongo_Db only for databse purpose

Comment: I think `remove` only returns the number of documents deleted, not the documents themselves.

Comment: @Joe yes u r right and now i am unable to think of any way to do this easily.

Comment: Perhaps before running `remove`, do a `find` with the same filter, and project to return just the `students` array.  Flattening that should give what you need for the final remove, assuming the array fits in a 16MB document, of course.

Comment: @Joe would be nice if u help me with code

Comment: @PrasoonShukla You should use Mongoose middleware for doing this. See https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre

Comment: did the answer work with you ?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would try and find the school.  That is the last thing I would want to delete since we need the ID and information from it.

`const school = await schools.findOne({ _id: req.parmas.schoolId })`

So now that I have the information from the school, I'll move on and try to delete the Courses.  Since the students are stored in an array, I'd leave those alone and only focus on removing the course.

`Course.remove({ 'students.type': school._id })`.

After removing the course(s), you should then delete the school.

`school.remove()`

Answer (score 0):

**Solution #1**

1. find the school.
2. find the courses with school.courses.
3. map through courses.
4. deleteMany students with course.students.
5. delete courses.
6. delete school.

   ```
   app.get("/fetchSchool/:schoolId", async (req, res) => {
    const schoolId = req.params.schoolId;

    try {
        // find one school
        const findSchool = await schools.findOne({ _id: schoolId });

        if (findSchool) {
            // find the courses in the school.courses
            const findCourses = await courses.find({ _id: { $in: findSchool.courses } });

            if (findCourses) {
                // map through courses to get every course
                findCourses.map(async (course) => {
                    // find the students in the mapped course AND remove them
                    const deleteStudents = await students.deleteMany({ _id: { $in: course.students } })

                    if (deleteStudents) {
                        // Remove the courses
                        const deletedCourses = await courses.deleteMany({ _id: { $in: findSchool.courses } });

                        if (deletedCourses) {
                            // Remove the school
                            const deletedSchool = await schools.deleteOne({ _id: schoolId });

                            if (deletedSchool) {
                                res.status(200).send('Deleted (school, courses, students) successfully');
                            } else { res.send("school not deleted") }

                        } else { res.send("courses not deleted") }

                    } else { res.send("courses not deleted") }
                })

            } else { res.send("no courses") }

        } else { res.send("no school") }

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send('some error occured, ' + error.message);
    }
   })
   ```

---

**Solution #2**

You can use **Pre** and **Post** hooks in Mongoose, but make sure to write it before mongoose.model() line in the model file.